# How to use a Foreach in a base type list in C#

Tags: c#, generics, foreach

I have a list of type GameObject called "Within" in each of my Tiles.

```
List<GameObject> Within = new List<GameObject>();
```

GameObject has derived classes of types `Bee`, `Flower` and `Tree`.

I am doing a `foreach` that should detect all bees inside the list and select or unselect them.

```
foreach (Bee bee in Tile.Within)
{
    bee.selected = !bee.selected;
}
```

Problem is, when I do that, if the list has an object of type `Flower` or `Tree`, I get an Exception:

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'WindowsGame2.Flower' to type 'WindowsGame2.Bee'."
```

I thought that the `foreach` would ignore all objects that don't fit in the description when we call it, but it doesn't... How can I get it to work?

Comment: Does your game object have a property (string) that describes the type of object ? If not, it can help to avoid having to reflect the type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about filtering using LINQ inside the foreach?

```
foreach (Bee bee in Tile.Within.OfType<Bee>())
{
    bee.selected = !bee.selected;
}
```

That will only select the Bee's and no flowers or trees.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of assistance :)

Comment: Please note, if you're making an Xbox360 game using XNA, this may generate garbage to be collected.

Comment: @jv42 - How will this create any more garbage than your approach? Any documentation to support that?

Comment: Well, what is a LINQ query doing? It creates a temporary list of objects, doesn't it? This list will have to be collected at some point. I think using Reflector would provide you with documentation enough, but I'll admit I haven't tried this.

Comment: @jv42 - Yes, it does. But in your example, you do this on each iteration of your loop: `Bee bee = gameObj as Bee;`. That creates a temporary object as well right? So im not saying it does not create a temporary object, I'm just saying that it isn't any different. At least not for the garbage collector.

Comment: I don't think the line you quoted allocates anything, assuming Bee is a reference type, it's only syntactic sugar, nothing else.

Comment: `Bee bee = something` That is an allocation right? It creates the local variable `bee` that gets assigned the result of something.

Comment: @jv42: linq to objects generally does not create lists.  Rather, it's more like the call to OfType allocates an "OfType" iterator, which iterates over the underlying collection, skipping objects that are not of the specified type.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen `Bee bee = gameObj as Bee` *does not allocate a new object on the heap*.  Rather, it allocates a reference of type Bee (most likely on the stack) and makes that reference point to the already-allocated gameObj if it is a Bee or derived type, or makes it a null reference if gameObj cannot be referenced as a Bee.

Comment: @phoog OK, so the 'OfType' construct is the one to go with there.

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` can be modified as follows:

```
foreach (GameObject gameObj in Tile.Within) 
{
    Bee bee = gameObj as Bee;
    if(bee != null)
    {
        bee.selected = !bee.selected; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) in your project?

```
foreach (Bee bee in Tile.Within.Where(o=>o is Bee))
{
    bee.selected = !bee.selected;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` doesn't work that way. It will just 'cast' the object to the requested type.

So you need to either filter beforehand (which might create garbage, if you're on Xbox360, this might be an issue), or filter in your loop.

There are several ways to do that, revolving around the use of either `as` or `is` or both. For instance:

```
foreach (GameObject gameObj in Tile.Within) 
{
    if (gameObj is Bee)
    {
        Bee bee = (Bee)gameObj;
        bee.selected = !bee.selected; 
    }
}
```

Comment: !bee.selected; --> `bee` undeclared identifier.

Comment: `if (x is Bee) ...` should be followed by `Bee bee = (Bee)gameObj;`, but you will save a runtime type check if you do `Bee bee = gameObj as Bee; if (bee != null) ...`

Comment: @phoog Fixed. The alternative is in another post.

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration you should check the type of the current item. If it is a `Bee` cast the result and do your work.

```
foreach (var item in Tile.Within)
{
    if (item is Bee)
    {
        ((Bee)item).Selected = !((Bee)item).Selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Azodious' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8341333/588868) is better, as there is less cast. Here is why : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182271.aspx

Comment: You're right but now I know the `OfType<T>` things changed for me ;)